# Help with installation (graphics card?)

Tags: system-installation, graphics, multiple-monitors

I recently upgraded some hardware on an older machine I have. My build consists of the following:

1. AMD FX-6350
2. ASUS - M5A97 R2.0 (motherboard)
3. ASUS - R7 370 Strix [Outputs ONLY: DVI, Displayport]

I am trying to install, and I end up with blank screens. I tried 'nomodeset' and 'nolapic' in the settings before boot with no luck.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I could really use the help...

Thanks!

Comment: Could anyone offer some advice? I posted this in Fedora's forums and never got a response either...